# awk remove duplicates based on two columns and custom duplication rule

Tags: linux, csv, awk

I want to process a CSV input file like the following :

```
a;b
b;c
b;a
c;d
x;y
d;c
```

and remove both duplicate lines defined by the rule : `a;b` and `b;a` are considered duplicate and therefore should be removed, the same rule applies to `c;d` and `d;c` they shoud be removed.

I tried to process file twice and use the condition `NR==FNR` to figure which pass it is (first or second) but i can't figure out how to implement the test on the duplication rule i defined above.

please help me

Comment: Do you mean for those two strings only, or all duplicates (eg `y;x`, `c;b`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk -F';' '{ks[$0]; a[$2 FS $1]++} END{for(k in ks) if(!a[k]) print k}' file

x;y
b;c
```

Answer (score 1):

Would you please try the following:

```
awk -F';' '
NR==FNR {                                       # 1st pass
    if (seen[$1$2]++ || seen[$2$1]++) {         # if "ab" or "ba" already exists
        dupe[$1";"$2]++; dupe[$2";"$1]++        # then mark "a;b" and "b;a" as duplicates
    }
    next
}
! dupe[$0]                                      # print unless duplicates
' file file
```

Output:

```
b;c
x;y
```